# Configure Rake with --trace

Tags: ruby, configuration, rake

I wonder why `rake` doesn't print the backtrace by default, but I know it irritates me when I have to run a task again just to get an idea of where the error occurs.

Is there a way to configure my system (ideally system wide or else project wise) so I don't have to type the `--trace`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the RAKEOPT environment variable is what you need. Check out this [discussion](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/185271).

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't seem to have been merged into MRI :-(  I'm not sure if there is an easy way to override it with the github head?

Comment: If you want it as a permanent system-wide change, you could just monkey-patch application.rb? Not ideal I know but rake config seems pretty limited otherwise...